# MagicalRecords fetch data from fetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have add this `fetchedResultsController` to my `UIViewController`. I am using MagicalRecords.

This is my code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    _fetchedResultsController = [Artist fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"artist_id" ascending:NO delegate:self];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

But this code does not invoke.

I have `UITableView` in my `UIViewController`. I suppose that this method below should starts the method above but it does not:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id  sectionInfo =
    [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

So the goal is fetch data using magical records and `fetchedResultsController`.

I can of course make something like `-findAll` but as I think fetchedResultsController will update data automatically when it will come instead of `-findAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a property (if you haven't done yet):

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

in the view controller,
and then access it via the *property accessor* and not the *instance variable*, e.g.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

`self.fetchedResultsController` calls the getter method `fetchedResultsController`, so that the FRC is created on the first call.

You should also set

```
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

inside the getter method to enable automatic change tracking, and call

```
[_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

for the initial fetch (unless MagicalRecord does that for you).